# SSAS Dimension architecture

Tags: ssas, cube

SSAS2008, but is more a design question.
I'm having a survey table, a survey-answers, a questions table and also a option table. Option containts the textual response posibilities to the specific questions.
This is all quite easy to model.
The questions are a parent-child dimension.

But, now i would like to have the option to query for example give me all the responses from people to the question B(and subquestions) that have answered to question A with option x.

I've created a dupliated Question/Option dimension that could be used for filtering but not I cant get a nice relation ship between the answers and the filter.

This is my structure http://www.dewildeeend.be/images/Harry/Capture.PNG

Any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That picture doesnt look like a DW to me.

Try combining all the tables to single Answer DW Fact table, then make the dimension tables as you desire:

Response dimension, with hieararchy

People dimension

and

Answer fact